# Save form data temporary

Tags: symfony

The user has the ability to filter a list of data. For this use case i build a form type "UserFilterType", which look like this.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('firstName', 'text', array('attr' => array('maxlength' => 255)))
             ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'ApplicationUserBundle:Role',
                'property' => 'name',
                'label' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'empty_value' => 'msg.role.all',
                'translation_domain' => 'role', 'required' => false)
             ));
}
```

So far everything works very well. The user can filter the output. But if the user wants to sort the output, eg by first name. A get request executed and filter options lost. I will save the filter options temporary, maybe in a session.

I try the following option:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->set('userFilter', serialize($form->getData());
.....
$form->setData(unserialize($session->set('userFilter')));
```

The form fields are filled out correctly, but if i execute the filter again with a post request i get the following error message

"Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?"

Does anyone have any idea how I should proceed? I hope I could describe my problem understandable.

Comment: get a var_dump of the data after unserialize.

Comment: I don't know if it's the error but... $form->setData(unserialize($session->set('userFilter'))); should be $form->setData(unserialize($session->get('userFilter')));

Comment: Ok, i think the getData() return only the selected Entity from the choice field, but the form need an array of entities for this choice field. I can retrieve the entities from database and analyze which is selected by user and setData with entities into 
form. But how can i define on setting choice field parameters, which one is selected / checked? Or is that a wrong approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of field type 'entity', you might want to use 'choice' and set the querybuilder for the choicelist in the form.

This is caused by the fact, that 'entity' type field expects an Entity as a value. When you unserialize the data, even if it was an Entity from the database, the EntityManager doesn't know this(the unserialized object is just an instance of ApplicationUserBundle:Role, it might not be in the database yet) so this is not a "managed" entity.

You can also add the EntityManager that you found a "lost lamb" and add it back to the manager by:

```
$filters = unserialize($session->set('userFilter'));
$roles = $filters['roles'];
$entityManager->merge($roles);
```

This way you tell the EntityManager that this object is already persisted(through ->persist) and EntityManager should treat it as an object fetched from the database
but you need to test it